# Prevent div scroll on tab and focus

Tags: html, scroll, intersection-observer

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;    
}

.card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 0 0 100px;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have a div which is scrolling horizontally.  Each item has a certain focusable element like button.  I am programmatically scrolling the div when needed and want to prevent the auto scroll of the div when user is tabbing through the elements.
Is there a simple way to prevent it?
One option i am thinking is to use intersection observer and set visibility hidden to elements outside the scroll so the tab does't go to those elements.  Is any other simple way?

CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;    
}

.card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Click on the first button and start tabbing, I dont want the focus to go to card-4 and scroll the div.

Comment: Then you have to set the `tabindex="-1"` to every element you don't want to be focusable. You can't prevent the scroll, this is default behaviour and would confuse the user if this were to be disabled.